# Deadlock due to hash collision?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, deadlock, database-deadlocks

I have a deadlock, which is occuring with exclusive lock on the same clustered index, by two different process IDs. The Database is on RCSI mode. I have two questions.

1) Besides overlapping rows by the two UPDATE statements, would this be likely caused by the hash collision?

2) In the trace XML file below, the query has parameters on it. What events should I trace with SQL Profiler to get the parameter values?

Appreciate the help. Thanks

The trace XML file

```xml
<deadlock-list>
 <deadlock victim="process8ad948">
  <process-list>
   <process id="process8ad948" taskpriority="0" logused="164520" waitresource="KEY: 7:72057601661599744 (01c1926aca97)" waittime="2833" ownerId="7491036" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2012-10-08T13:16:03.067" XDES="0x6b561b950" lockMode="U" schedulerid="4" kpid="2476" status="suspended" spid="94" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2012-10-08T13:16:57.753" lastbatchcompleted="2012-10-08T13:16:57.750" clientapp="PeopleSoft" hostname="STGAAMY-PPSAPP" hostpid="31772" loginname="HRTRNADM" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="7491036" currentdb="7" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
    <executionStack>
     <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="440" sqlhandle="0x020000007b8741293b8e4d6542633962bc48489d3946a5d1">
UPDATE PS_GP_NEW_RTO_WRK SET ORIG_CAL_RUN_ID = (SELECT DISTINCT C.ORIG_CAL_RUN_ID FROM PS_GP_PYE_PRC_STAT B ,PS_GP_OLD_RTO_WRK C WHERE C.EMPLID BETWEEN @P1 AND @P2 AND C.CAL_RUN_ID=@P3 AND C.EMPLID = PS_GP_NEW_RTO_WRK.EMPLID AND C.CAL_RUN_ID = PS_GP_NEW_RTO_WRK.CAL_RUN_ID AND C.EMPL_RCD = PS_GP_NEW_RTO_WRK.EMPL_RCD AND C.CAL_ID = PS_GP_NEW_RTO_WRK.CAL_ID AND C.GP_PAYGROUP = PS_GP_NEW_RTO_WRK.GP_PAYGROUP AND B.CAL_ID= C.CAL_ID AND B.GP_PAYGROUP= C.GP_PAYGROUP AND B.EMPLID=C.EMPLID AND B.EMPL_RCD=C.EMPL_RCD AND B.ORIG_CAL_RUN_ID=C.ORIG_CAL_RUN_ID AND C.SEL_ACTION IN (N&apos;R&apos;,N&apos;Z&apos;) AND B.SEL_ACTION=N&apos;A&apos;) WHERE EMPLID BETWEEN @P4 AND @P5 AND CAL_RUN_ID=@P6 AND (N&apos;N&apos;=@P7 OR EMPLID IN (SELECT EMPLID FROM PS_GP_GRP_LIST_RUN WHERE RUN_CNTL_ID=@P8 AND OPRID=@P9) ) AND EXISTS (SELECT B.ORIG_CAL_RUN_ID FROM PS_GP_PYE_PRC_STAT B ,PS_GP_OLD_RTO_WRK C WHERE C.EMPLID BETWEEN @P10 AND @P11 AND C.CAL_RUN_ID=@P12 AND C.EMPLID = PS_GP_NEW_RTO_WRK.EMPLID AND C.CAL_RUN_ID = PS_GP_NEW_RTO_WRK.CAL_RUN_ID AND C.EMPL_RCD = PS_GP_NEW_RTO     </frame>
     <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown     </frame>
    </executionStack>
    <inputbuf>
(@P1 nvarchar(508),@P2 nvarchar(508),@P3 nvarchar(508),@P4 nvarchar(508),@P5 nvarchar(508),@P6 nvarchar(508),@P7 nvarchar(508),@P8 nvarchar(508),@P9 nvarchar(508),@P10 nvarchar(508),@P11 nvarchar(508),@P12 nvarchar(508))UPDATE PS_GP_NEW_RTO_WRK SET ORIG_CAL_RUN_ID = (SELECT DISTINCT C.ORIG_CAL_RUN_ID FROM PS_GP_PYE_PRC_STAT B ,PS_GP_OLD_RTO_WRK C WHERE C.EMPLID BETWEEN @P1 AND @P2 AND C.CAL_RUN_ID=@P3 AND C.EMPLID = PS_GP_NEW_RTO_WRK.EMPLID AND C.CAL_RUN_ID = PS_GP_NEW_RTO_WRK.CAL_RUN_ID AND C.EMPL_RCD = PS_GP_NEW_RTO_WRK.EMPL_RCD AND C.CAL_ID = PS_GP_NEW_RTO_WRK.CAL_ID AND C.GP_PAYGROUP = PS_GP_NEW_RTO_WRK.GP_PAYGROUP AND B.CAL_ID= C.CAL_ID AND B.GP_PAYGROUP= C.GP_PAYGROUP AND B.EMPLID=C.EMPLID AND B.EMPL_RCD=C.EMPL_RCD AND B.ORIG_CAL_RUN_ID=C.ORIG_CAL_RUN_ID AND C.SEL_ACTION IN (N&apos;R&apos;,N&apos;Z&apos;) AND B.SEL_ACTION=N&apos;A&apos;) WHERE EMPLID BETWEEN @P4 AND @P5 AND CAL_RUN_ID=@P6 AND (N&apos;N&apos;=@P7 OR EMPLID IN (SELECT EMPLID FROM PS_GP_GRP_LIST_RUN WHERE RUN_CNTL_ID=@P8 AND OPRID=@P9) ) AND EXISTS (SELECT B.ORIG_CAL_RUN_ID FRO    </inputbuf>
   </process>
   <process id="process5ff948" taskpriority="0" logused="2793096" waitresource="KEY: 7:72057601661599744 (9e1bb6c02ace)" waittime="1659" ownerId="7509883" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2012-10-08T13:16:50.867" XDES="0x6b6beb950" lockMode="U" schedulerid="1" kpid="2472" status="suspended" spid="95" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2012-10-08T13:16:59.400" lastbatchcompleted="2012-10-08T13:16:59.400" clientapp="PeopleSoft" hostname="STGAAMY-PPSAPP" hostpid="32912" loginname="HRTRNADM" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="7509883" currentdb="7" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
    <executionStack>
     <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="440" sqlhandle="0x020000007b8741293b8e4d6542633962bc48489d3946a5d1">
UPDATE PS_GP_NEW_RTO_WRK SET ORIG_CAL_RUN_ID = (SELECT DISTINCT C.ORIG_CAL_RUN_ID FROM PS_GP_PYE_PRC_STAT B ,PS_GP_OLD_RTO_WRK C WHERE C.EMPLID BETWEEN @P1 AND @P2 AND C.CAL_RUN_ID=@P3 AND C.EMPLID = PS_GP_NEW_RTO_WRK.EMPLID AND C.CAL_RUN_ID = PS_GP_NEW_RTO_WRK.CAL_RUN_ID AND C.EMPL_RCD = PS_GP_NEW_RTO_WRK.EMPL_RCD AND C.CAL_ID = PS_GP_NEW_RTO_WRK.CAL_ID AND C.GP_PAYGROUP = PS_GP_NEW_RTO_WRK.GP_PAYGROUP AND B.CAL_ID= C.CAL_ID AND B.GP_PAYGROUP= C.GP_PAYGROUP AND B.EMPLID=C.EMPLID AND B.EMPL_RCD=C.EMPL_RCD AND B.ORIG_CAL_RUN_ID=C.ORIG_CAL_RUN_ID AND C.SEL_ACTION IN (N&apos;R&apos;,N&apos;Z&apos;) AND B.SEL_ACTION=N&apos;A&apos;) WHERE EMPLID BETWEEN @P4 AND @P5 AND CAL_RUN_ID=@P6 AND (N&apos;N&apos;=@P7 OR EMPLID IN (SELECT EMPLID FROM PS_GP_GRP_LIST_RUN WHERE RUN_CNTL_ID=@P8 AND OPRID=@P9) ) AND EXISTS (SELECT B.ORIG_CAL_RUN_ID FROM PS_GP_PYE_PRC_STAT B ,PS_GP_OLD_RTO_WRK C WHERE C.EMPLID BETWEEN @P10 AND @P11 AND C.CAL_RUN_ID=@P12 AND C.EMPLID = PS_GP_NEW_RTO_WRK.EMPLID AND C.CAL_RUN_ID = PS_GP_NEW_RTO_WRK.CAL_RUN_ID AND C.EMPL_RCD = PS_GP_NEW_RTO     </frame>
     <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown     </frame>
    </executionStack>
    <inputbuf>
(@P1 nvarchar(508),@P2 nvarchar(508),@P3 nvarchar(508),@P4 nvarchar(508),@P5 nvarchar(508),@P6 nvarchar(508),@P7 nvarchar(508),@P8 nvarchar(508),@P9 nvarchar(508),@P10 nvarchar(508),@P11 nvarchar(508),@P12 nvarchar(508))UPDATE PS_GP_NEW_RTO_WRK SET ORIG_CAL_RUN_ID = (SELECT DISTINCT C.ORIG_CAL_RUN_ID FROM PS_GP_PYE_PRC_STAT B ,PS_GP_OLD_RTO_WRK C WHERE C.EMPLID BETWEEN @P1 AND @P2 AND C.CAL_RUN_ID=@P3 AND C.EMPLID = PS_GP_NEW_RTO_WRK.EMPLID AND C.CAL_RUN_ID = PS_GP_NEW_RTO_WRK.CAL_RUN_ID AND C.EMPL_RCD = PS_GP_NEW_RTO_WRK.EMPL_RCD AND C.CAL_ID = PS_GP_NEW_RTO_WRK.CAL_ID AND C.GP_PAYGROUP = PS_GP_NEW_RTO_WRK.GP_PAYGROUP AND B.CAL_ID= C.CAL_ID AND B.GP_PAYGROUP= C.GP_PAYGROUP AND B.EMPLID=C.EMPLID AND B.EMPL_RCD=C.EMPL_RCD AND B.ORIG_CAL_RUN_ID=C.ORIG_CAL_RUN_ID AND C.SEL_ACTION IN (N&apos;R&apos;,N&apos;Z&apos;) AND B.SEL_ACTION=N&apos;A&apos;) WHERE EMPLID BETWEEN @P4 AND @P5 AND CAL_RUN_ID=@P6 AND (N&apos;N&apos;=@P7 OR EMPLID IN (SELECT EMPLID FROM PS_GP_GRP_LIST_RUN WHERE RUN_CNTL_ID=@P8 AND OPRID=@P9) ) AND EXISTS (SELECT B.ORIG_CAL_RUN_ID FRO    </inputbuf>
   </process>
  </process-list>
  <resource-list>
   <keylock hobtid="72057601661599744" dbid="7" objectname="HRTRN91.dbo.PS_GP_NEW_RTO_WRK" indexname="PS_GP_NEW_RTO_WRK" id="lock4991e6c00" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057601661599744">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="process5ff948" mode="X"/>
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="process8ad948" mode="U" requestType="wait"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </keylock>
   <keylock hobtid="72057601661599744" dbid="7" objectname="HRTRN91.dbo.PS_GP_NEW_RTO_WRK" indexname="PS_GP_NEW_RTO_WRK" id="lockdf24e800" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057601661599744">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="process8ad948" mode="X"/>
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="process5ff948" mode="U" requestType="wait"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </keylock>
  </resource-list>
 </deadlock>
</deadlock-list>
```

The table structure

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PS_GP_NEW_RTO_WRK](
    [EMPLID] [nvarchar](11) NOT NULL,
    [CAL_RUN_ID] [nvarchar](18) NOT NULL,
    [EMPL_RCD] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [GP_PAYGROUP] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [CAL_ID] [nvarchar](18) NOT NULL,
    [ORIG_CAL_RUN_ID] [nvarchar](18) NOT NULL,
    [RSLT_VER_NUM] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [RSLT_REV_NUM] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [PRC_ORD_TS] [dbo].[PSDATETIME] NULL,
    [SEL_STAT] [nvarchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [SEL_RSN] [nvarchar](2) NOT NULL,
    [RTO_PRC_ID] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [PYMT_DT] [dbo].[PSDATE] NULL,
    [PRC_BGN_DT] [dbo].[PSDATE] NULL,
    [PRC_END_DT] [dbo].[PSDATE] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PS_GP_NEW_RTO_WRK] SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = ENABLE)
GO
```

The Index Structure

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [PS_GP_NEW_RTO_WRK] ON [dbo].[PS_GP_NEW_RTO_WRK] 
(
    [EMPLID] ASC,
    [CAL_RUN_ID] ASC,
    [EMPL_RCD] ASC,
    [GP_PAYGROUP] ASC,
    [CAL_ID] ASC,
    [ORIG_CAL_RUN_ID] ASC
)
    WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, 
    STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, 
    SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, 
    IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
    DROP_EXISTING = OFF, 
    ONLINE = OFF, 
    ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, 
    ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Answer (score 3):

1) Restore a backup on a dev/test server and run this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT [EMPLID],[CAL_RUN_ID],[EMPL_RCD],[GP_PAYGROUP],[CAL_ID],[ORIG_CAL_RUN_ID], %%lockres%% AS KeyLockID
    FROM [dbo].[PS_GP_NEW_RTO_WRK]
) x
WHERE x.KeyLockID IN ('(01c1926aca97)','(9e1bb6c02ace)')
```

The `(01c1926aca97)` and `(9e1bb6c02ace)` values are the "lock id's" (see /deadlock-list/deadlock/process-list/process/@waitresource values: `KEY: 7:72057601661599744 (01c1926aca97)`, `KEY: 7:72057601661599744 (9e1bb6c02ace)`).
If you get 3 or more rows then the answer is yes.

2) Also, you may check for diff. plans:

```
SELECT qp.*, txt.*
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans cp
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(cp.plan_handle) qp
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(cp.plan_handle) txt
WHERE txt.text LIKE N'UPDATE PS\_GP\_NEW\_RTO\_WRK SET ORIG\_CAL\_RUN\_ID = (SELECT DISTINCT C.ORIG\_CAL\_RUN\_ID FROM PS\_GP\_PYE\_PRC\_STAT B ,PS\_GP\_OLD\_RTO\_WRK C WHERE C.EMPLID BETWEEN @P1 AND @P2 AND C.CAL\_RUN\_ID=@P3 AND C.EMPLID = PS\_GP\_NEW\_RTO\_WRK.EMPLID AND C.CAL\_RUN\_ID = PS\_GP\_NEW\_RTO\_WRK.CAL\_RUN\_ID AND C.EMPL\_RCD = PS\_GP\_NEW\_RTO\_WRK.EMPL\_RCD AND C.CAL\_ID = PS\_GP\_NEW\_RTO\_WRK.CAL\_ID AND C.GP\_PAYGROUP = PS\_GP\_NEW\_RTO\_WRK.GP\_PAYGROUP AND B.CAL\_ID= C.CAL\_ID AND B.GP\_PAYGROUP= C.GP\_PAYGROUP AND B.EMPLID=C.EMPLID AND B.EMPL\_RCD=C.EMPL\_RCD AND B.ORIG\_CAL\_RUN\_ID=C.ORIG\_CAL\_RUN\_ID AND C.SEL\_ACTION IN (N&apos;R&apos;,N&apos;Z&apos;) AND B.SEL\_ACTION=N&apos;A&apos;) WHERE EMPLID BETWEEN @P4 AND @P5 AND CAL\_RUN\_ID=@P6 AND (N&apos;N&apos;=@P7 OR EMPLID IN (SELECT EMPLID FROM PS\_GP\_GRP\_LIST\_RUN WHERE RUN\_CNTL\_ID=@P8 AND OPRID=@P9) ) AND EXISTS (SELECT B.ORIG\_CAL\_RUN\_ID FROM PS\_GP\_PYE\_PRC\_STAT B ,PS\_GP\_OLD\_RTO\_WRK C WHERE C.EMPLID BETWEEN @P10 AND @P11 AND C.CAL\_RUN\_ID=@P12 AND C.EMPLID = PS\_GP\_NEW\_RTO\_WRK.EMPLID AND C.CAL\_RUN\_ID = PS\_GP\_NEW\_RTO\_WRK.CAL\_RUN\_ID AND C.EMPL\_RCD = PS\_GP\_NEW\_RTO%' ESCAPE N'\'
ORDER BY txt.text

SELECT qp.*, txt.*
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans cp
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(cp.plan_handle) qp
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(cp.plan_handle) txt
WHERE txt.text LIKE N'(@P1 nvarchar(508),@P2 nvarchar(508),@P3 nvarchar(508),@P4 nvarchar(508),@P5 nvarchar(508),@P6 nvarchar(508),@P7 nvarchar(508),@P8 nvarchar(508),@P9 nvarchar(508),@P10 nvarchar(508),@P11 nvarchar(508),@P12 nvarchar(508))UPDATE PS\_GP\_NEW\_RTO\_WRK SET ORIG\_CAL\_RUN\_ID = (SELECT DISTINCT C.ORIG\_CAL\_RUN\_ID FROM PS\_GP\_PYE\_PRC\_STAT B ,PS\_GP\_OLD\_RTO\_WRK C WHERE C.EMPLID BETWEEN @P1 AND @P2 AND C.CAL\_RUN\_ID=@P3 AND C.EMPLID = PS\_GP\_NEW\_RTO\_WRK.EMPLID AND C.CAL\_RUN\_ID = PS\_GP\_NEW\_RTO\_WRK.CAL\_RUN\_ID AND C.EMPL\_RCD = PS\_GP\_NEW\_RTO\_WRK.EMPL\_RCD AND C.CAL\_ID = PS\_GP\_NEW\_RTO\_WRK.CAL\_ID AND C.GP\_PAYGROUP = PS\_GP\_NEW\_RTO\_WRK.GP\_PAYGROUP AND B.CAL\_ID= C.CAL\_ID AND B.GP\_PAYGROUP= C.GP\_PAYGROUP AND B.EMPLID=C.EMPLID AND B.EMPL\_RCD=C.EMPL\_RCD AND B.ORIG\_CAL\_RUN\_ID=C.ORIG\_CAL\_RUN\_ID AND C.SEL\_ACTION IN (N&apos;R&apos;,N&apos;Z&apos;) AND B.SEL\_ACTION=N&apos;A&apos;) WHERE EMPLID BETWEEN @P4 AND @P5 AND CAL\_RUN\_ID=@P6 AND (N&apos;N&apos;=@P7 OR EMPLID IN (SELECT EMPLID FROM PS\_GP\_GRP\_LIST\_RUN WHERE RUN\_CNTL\_ID=@P8 AND OPRID=@P9) ) AND EXISTS (SELECT B.ORIG\_CAL\_RUN\_ID FRO%' ESCAPE N'\'
ORDER BY txt.text
```

If you get different plans for every UPDATE or (@...)UPDATE statement (ex. a serial plan and a parallel plan) then this fact excludes the initial hypothesis (hash collisions).

**Extended comment:**
[image]

T   = SPID94 starts to execute the UPDATE statement (serial plan)

T+1 = SPID95 starts to execute the UPDATE statement (parallel plan)

T+2 = SPID94 takes a X lock on row/key 4

T+3 = SPID95-thread1 tries to take a U lock on row/key 4 (already locked by SPID94).
Also, SPID95-thread2 takes a X lock on row/key 9.

T+4 = SPID94 tries to take a U lock on row/key 9 (already locked by SPID95).

Conclusion: SPID94 has a X lock on row/key 4 and requests a U lock on row/key 9. SPID95 has a X lock on row/key 9 and requests a U lock on row/key 4. So, we have a deadlock.

Comment: *** this fact *may* excludes ***

Comment: Thanks Bogdan, I get point number 1 but on point 2 why would having different serial and parallel plan for every update statement exclude the cause for hash collision?

Comment: Two diff. plans may explain the deadlock not the hash collision. Usually, an UPDATE statement takes a U lock on a row/key, verifies the filter (WHERE) and if the filter is true then the U lock is converted to a X lock. Look at my comment (last answer). Also, try to publish the execution plans of these two UPDATEs.